# Is there something that will completely cover two gangs of my electrical box below the drywall?

Tags: electrical

I previously installed a four gang box in a house. The problem with that box was it ended up being that it was so long that half of the box will be in the backsplash of the kitchen counter and half not in the backsplash.

I was thinking of covering two gangs of the box with possibly a piece of metal covering that would go on the device box (than drywalled over). I will replace it with another 2 gang box above or below it (therefore all four 3 way switches will have a home). I really wish they just had three way rocker switches. But they actually only have rockers switches that are a single pole and three way switch in one. No double 3 way rocker switches...

I cannot ungang the box since it's a solid 4 gang device box and I do not want to slide it out to replace with a 2 gang because it took a lot of fastening on both sides of the box, and the wall is finished and painted! (Heck maybe I will take it out).

So I believe from a code standpoint that should be fine since the box is still accessible (from the other two gangs...nothing will be in the end two that I want to cover). So do they have a part for this. I cannot think of a name of one. I just wanna be ready for tomorrow.

Comment: You mean [these](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=double+3+way+switch&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=42754879187&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9421989540859149981&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_1y85lzg65k_b)? You find a triple, let me know ;p

Comment: If you can cover it with drywall, that box is way too far back. 1/4" maximum gap from finished surface.

Comment: I would just do it the right way and open the wall, split the circuits and move to the two boxes as needed. If you can make the 2 x 3way switches that @Mazura located work for you you can then change out that box to a two gang box.

Comment: Thats a good point. Drywall will never be able to cover it since the plates would be flush. And I had never seen those double three way switches before. I spent a night on Levitons sight and couldn't find them in days gone past. Yup looks like the long way for me, and more holes on the finished wall for friend. But hey if they want it... Oh steel studs and how everything is difficult! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Code pertaining to electric junction boxes is pretty clear when it states boxes are to remain accessible and uncovered.

Comment: This is more of a comment but I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

Take it out, and do it right.  According to my favorite section of the National Electrical Code, "*Electrical equipment shall be installed in a neat and workmanlike manner.*" (110.12).